# How to structure hierarchical data in oracle

Tags: oracle, data-structures, graph, tree, hierarchy

I need to store hierarchical data using a relational database (specifically oracle). 
So far the only implementation I used was the Adjacency list. However this time I have some requirements which are denying the use of this structure.

The requirements are, that (1) each Node can be used in different hierarchies and (2) the edge connecting the node to a different hierarchy may be different weighted.

An example of 2 hierarchies is given here:

[image]

So I need an advice on how to tackle that problem or pointing out the obvious solution if you have one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create association table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE ASSOC (
   PARENT_ID      NUMBER,
   CHILD_ID       NUMBER,
   WEIGHT         NUMBER,
   HIERARCHY_ID   VARCHAR2(100));  -- necessary do distinguish, which hierarchy connection belongs to
```

and data

```
PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID  WEIGHT  HIERARCHY_ID
----------+---------+-------+-------------
1         | 2       | 50    | A 
1         | 5       | 50    | A 
2         | 3       | 70    | A 
2         | 4       | 30    | A 
10        | 2       | 65    | B
10        | 5       | 35    | B
...
```